# Need to redirect an output to /dev/null.... works fine in command line but not in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rhel5, lvm

I need to write an execute some command in bash file and ignore the inputs.

Example

```
pvs --noheadings -o pv_name,vg_name,vg_size 2> /dev/null
```

The above command works great in command line, but when I write the same in shell, it gives me an error

like

```
Failed to read physical volume "2>"
Failed to read physical volume "/dev/null"
```

I guess it looks it as an part of the whole command. Can you please give me some suggestions on how to rectify it?

Thanks in advance.

FULLCODE

#------------------------------

```
main() {
    pv_cmd='pvs'
    nh='--noheadings'
    sp=' '
    op='-o'
    vgn='vg_name'
    pvn='pv_name'
    pvz='pv_size'
    cm=','
    tonull=' 2 > /dev/null '
    pipe='|'

    #cmd=$pv_cmd$sp$nh$sp$op$sp$vgn$cm$pvn$cm$pvz$sp$pipe$tonull  #line A
    cmd='pvs --noheadings -o vg_name,pv_name,pv_size 2> /dev/null' #line B
    echo -n "Cmd="
    echo $cmd
    $cmd
```

}

main

#-----------------------------------------------------

If you look at the Line A & B both the versions are there, although one is commented out.....

Comment: what's your shell? it's probably not bash...

Comment: By "in shell", do you mean in a script file? If so, please show an *exact* copy of relevant part of your script.

Comment: its bash file.... yeah.... filename is main.sh and shabang is !/bin/bash

Comment: The single line itself is fine -- so you'll need to provide the entire script; this isn't enough information to debug.

Comment: Just in case... do you really have !/bin/bash or rather #!/bin/bash ?

Comment: Did you copy/paste the line, maybe the `>` is not an ascii `>`. Try retyping the command.

Comment: @Thor:I will paste the code in a new comment.... please see below...

Comment: @joval: Sorry, its #!/bin/bash.... i thought !/bin/bash is enough since I said shabang before... also, it would have given be bad interpreter error....

Comment: @Thor, I did..... I dont copy paste code after some bad previous experience... does not matter how small it is..... esp. not in bash...

Comment: Why are you trying to build up your command this way? If you want to do it programatically, the Right Way is with an array -- see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 -- but even then you can't include the redirections. Just put the literal command in your script and don't bother with the mucking with variables that's causing you all your trouble.

Comment: its just a prototype..... I am going to rebuild in Python, I have to deal with bash.... since I started with it.....  Thanks...

Comment: By the way, this doesn't work in the command line either, if you do it the same way you did in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't include the 2> /dev/null inside the quoted string. Quote removal happens *after* redirections are processed. You'll have to do

```
cmd='pvs --noheadings -o vg_name,pv_name,pv_size'
$cmd 2> /dev/null
```

for redirection to work properly.

Comment: This is still very bad practice -- `cmd=( cvs --noheadings -o vg_name,pv_size,pv_size ); "${cmd[@]}" 2>/dev/null` would be an equivalent that works with arguments containing whitespace, if there was really a reason to build the command in a variable like this. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Agreed; I stopped at providing the minimum change necessary to avoid the given error.

Answer (score 1):

The way you did it, 2> and /dev/null will be parsed as arguments. But you want 2> /dev/null to be bash code, not program argument, so

instead of

```
 $cmd
```

you should

```
 eval $cmd
```

That is how things work.

Or if the echo thing is for debugging, you can just set -o xtrace before the command and set +o xtrace after it. And do it the normal way instead of stuffing a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's going on is that there is some character inside the line that is either not visible to us or the `>` is a different character than it appears. After all the shell should swallow the redirect before the command gets to see it, but the command sees `2>` and `/dev/null` as `[PhysicalVolume [PhysicalVolume...]]`. Alternatively the redirection could be passed quoted (so it loses the special meaning to the shell and gets passed on), see chepner's answer.

---

```
tonull=' 2 > /dev/null '
```

is the issue. Exactly as chepner guessed.

Comment: No actually it thinks it as an device.... if you do man pvs, you will see "pvs --noheadings -o pv_name,pv_size,vg_name <devices>",, it thinks it as an devices.... please help////

Answer (score -1):

eliminate space between 2 and >

```
pvs --noheadings -o pv_name,vg_name,vg_size 2>/dev/null
```